# Grunt browserify transform ReactJS then bundle

Tags: gruntjs, reactjs, browserify

In my project I am using Grunt to build the javascript files, I have ReactJS components which makes Grunt complain about `Error: Parsing file` in one of my javascript file, caused by the JSX syntax:

```
"use strict";

var $ = require('jquery');
var React = require('react');
require('app/comments/comment_box_react.js');

$.fn.comment_box = function(options){
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.comment_box.defaults, options);
    var me = this;

    React.render(<CommentBox url="comments.json" />, this);
    return me;
}

$.fn.comment_box.defaults = {}
```

My browerify config in Grunt looks like this:

```
browserify: {
    main: {
        files: {
            '<%= paths.js_built %>/bundle.js': ['<%=paths.js %>/project.js'],
        }
    },
    transform: ['reactify'],
},
```

How do I perform transform first before the bundle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `gulp` and transform globally before bundle:

https://github.com/andreypopp/reactify/issues/66

```
gulp.task('activitiesjs', function() {
    browserify({
        entries: [
            paths.js+'/lib/activities/activities.js',
        ]
    }).transform(reactify, {global:true}).bundle().pipe(source('bundle.js')).pipe(gulp.dest(paths.js_built+'/activities'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The transform example in their docs has the `transform` array in an options object.

```
browserify: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'build/module.js': ['client/scripts/**/*.js', 'client/scripts/**/*.coffee'],
    },
    options: {
      transform: ['coffeeify']
    }
  }
}
```

Also, looks like your transform definition is outside of your `main` definition. Not sure if that would be global or not, so you might have to move it inside of main.  Something like this

```
browserify: {
    main: {
        files: {
            '<%= paths.js_built %>/bundle.js': ['<%=paths.js %>/project.js'],
        },
        options: {
            transform: ['reactify']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) the transform does happen globally but only happens after bundle. 2) I tried moving the transform inside still transform after bundle.